# Automatic HTML clean up

Tags: html, looking-for-a-script, best-practices

What are some of the most popular tools for automatically cleaning up HTML code to its cleanest and most *best practices* rendition?

The only one I know is the venerable HTMLtidy.

Please see [this](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml) for examples of best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Depends, there are several options and depending on your coding IDE. For example, [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) has some really nice built-in coding cleaner and can be extended by a gazillion of plugins for probably every coding language out there.

Of course, there are several other cleaning tools out there, but honestly, I have yet to find one which brings clean results out of the box, since lots of coders out there don't quite follow the standards to the dot.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean automatically cleaning up your own HTML code, Dreamweaver has commands to apply formatting and clean up XHTML code, along with a W3C validation check.

Speaking of which, that uses the [WC3 Markup and Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/), which allows for validation of a URI, uploaded file, and copy/pasting HTML code. The [WC3 HTML Tidy Service](http://services.w3.org/tidy/tidy) will also cleanup your HTML.

[Komodo Edit IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) has a number of formatting options and extensions (add-ons) that format and cleanup HTML, JS, CSS...and numerous other languages.

If you meant an automated script, there are a number of scripts and modules written for [tidyp](http://www.tidyp.com/), like the popular Perl module [HTML::Tidy](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/HTML-Tidy-1.54/lib/HTML/Tidy.pm)

Here's a [comparison of HTML Parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers), with HTML Tidy likely being the most popular, and used by the online WC3 HTML Tidy Service.